# How to reset Angular reactive form without clearing pre populated data?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a angular reactive form and some of the fields in the form are pre populated. I want to implement a 'Cancel' button that will reset all the changes to the form except the data that were pre populated when page was loaded. I tried the following but it resets the whole form:

```
resetForm() {
    this.myForm.reset();
  }
```

is there a way to reset only the current changes instead of resetting the whole form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `patchValue`

```
resetForm() {
  this.myForm.patchValue(initialValue);
}
```

`initialValue` is a object that holds populated values.